# Subactivity needs to be notified when main activity has an updated value

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a main activity which runs a Thread returning a result (let's say a string) to the main activity via Handler. I'm trying to create another Activity called from tha min activity, right after the mentioned Thread is created. This second activity will show the result (i.e. string field) coming from the main activity (sent by putting extras). So, the String value is initialized to a null value at first, and after some point of time. the Thread will update the value of the String. Therefore, I have to send this updated value to the second activity, which is already at the top of the Activity stack, and waiting for an updated value of that String.

I've looked around, but people discuss about onActivityResult() techniques. Do you have any idea about the implementation of this?

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible solutions:

- If your second activity (the receiver) has `SINGLE_TOP` attribute, you can send it an intent and process it in `Activity.onNewIntent()`. Intent's `SINGLE_TOP` flag should work as well.
- You may pass a handler from the receiver activity to a sender activity by `((SenderActivity) getParent()).setReceiverHandler(handler)` (this code resides in `ReceiverActivity`, `setReceiverHandler()` should be declared in `SenderActivity`) and use it to notify `ReceiverActivity` about any changes. **UPD:** This approach allows the communication between TabActivity and it's embedded activities. It wouldn't work in general case.

Comment: At your second proposal, ((SenderActivity) getParent()) returns null. Documentation says that getParent() returns the parent activity if this view is an embedded child. Then I changed the SenderActivity to extend ActivityGroup instead of Activity. But it also didn't work. What should be the way for those two activity to do what you wrote?

Comment: You're right. This method is used so often in our code that I considered it to be universal, when in fact it works only between TabActivity and it's children.

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend doing is in your activity where the Strin value is changed, listen for the change in that activity, and then based on the String value, start the new actvity. You coould have a button to display and check whether the text is null or not, and launch the activity accordingly.
This method seems feasible.